# "diff" Linux utility implementation in C

Tags: c, linux, diff, computer-science, variable-assignment

Our CS Professor gave us Assignment to implement the diff LINUX command by writing a C program.

I started off by extracting the lines of the two files passed as command line arguments in two different arrays (line1 & line2).

But what to do after that? How to report for changes like 1,3c2,4; 1d0; etc

INPUT will be something like this:

./diff file1.txt file2.txt

(where, diff is the compiled file name of the C Code which I need to write)

Read about what diff outputs here: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-diff-command-file-comparison/

(Or if you have LINUX, try using it there to see the output)

I need to implement only this part, no need to write additional code for extra functionalities like -c, etc.

I have written upto this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LSIZ 200 
#define RSIZ 100

// diff Implementation
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc == 1){printf("No file names given!\n"); exit(1);}         
    if(argc > 3){printf("Cannot have more than 2 file names!\n"); exit(1);}
    
    // FILE 1    
    char line1[RSIZ][LSIZ];
    
    FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f1==0){ perror("Error Opening the File!\n"); exit(1); } 

    int i1 = 0;
    int tot1 = 0;
    while(fgets(line1[i1], LSIZ, f1)){
        line1[i1][strlen(line1[i1]) - 1] = '\0';
        i1++;
    }
    tot1 = i1;   

    fclose(f1);

    // FILE 2    
    char line2[RSIZ][LSIZ];
    
    FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if(f2==0){ perror("Error Opening the File!\n"); exit(1); } 

    int i2 = 0;
    int tot2 = 0;
    while(fgets(line2[i2], LSIZ, f2)){
        line2[i2][strlen(line2[i2]) - 1] = '\0';
        i2++;
    }
    tot2 = i2;

    fclose(f2);    

}
```

Comment: Maybe the source code of diff can help: https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/

Comment: Try getting a CRC for every line and then compare CRCs.  It makes it easier to realign if lines have been added or deleted.  Also makes it simpler if there is an `ignore leading whitespace` option.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, `diff` is finding the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Computation) except it's for lines of text instead of individual letters.

Comment: @cup Thank You, I looked about it. But I later found out that this Program could be better approach via LCS Algo, DP.